Where do I connect the receiver for my wireless light switch?
I want to install a wireless switch with receiver to control my kitchen lights. They are 4 recessed lights currently controlled with a single switch which is accessible only from one side of the room.
I want to add this wireless switch so they can be controlled from the opposite side of the room as well.
Where do I connect the receiver? Behind the existing switch or in either one of the recessed lights

Depends on what hardware you use. I've done a similar task and for that brand you replaced the old switch with their switch, and then remotes (hand held or "switch" format) were paired with the main switch.

What do the instructions say?  If they are unclear, please help us help you by providing the make and model of the parts and a link to the data sheet and instructions.  Include a photo of the wiring behind the switch.  We may also want a pic of the wiring behind the first light in the line from the switch (but you can wait and see whether necessary, if that is inconvenient now).  What country are you in?

Replace the current switch with one that can be remotely controlled.
This is a great excuse to start playing with home automation, if you want one.

There are many ways.

You can buy a smart switch that will turn your existing lights on and off, and the switch can be controlled remotely by other smart switches, phone apps, Alexa, etc.   Different switches have different capabilities.

You can buy smart bulbs to put in your existing recessed fixtures.   Then, you can use smart switches just as noted above, or you can just leave your existing switch as a master power switch, leave it on all the time, and control the lights directly from smart switches, phone apps, etc.  If the lights are smart, the switch that provides them electric power does not have to be.  In fact, it's better not to have such a switch at all.

You can replace your recessed light fixtures with smart wafer lights that fit in the same holes in the ceiling.   It's similar to using smart bulbs but you can get much better light.



Why do you say the light from wafer lights is much better?  The lamps for recessed fixtures have options equivalent to wafers for color temperature, color rendering index (CRI), and light output.  Recessed have several advantages: they disperse light in a controlled manner, i.e., focus it where you want it, as in "flood" vs "spot".  In fact, they are available rated for various degrees of dispersion.  Some fixtures allow you to focus the light with a lens,  tilt the lamp to angle the light, or add baffles that reduce glare by shielding the light source from room occupants' line of sight.

@MadMonty I'm comparing putting Smart LED PAR bulbs into big old high hats versus replacing the cans with wafers that fit the holes. You seem to be describing something else, that does sound reasonable. But I'm not sure what it is.

I believe what I call "lamps for recessed fixtures" are what you term "LED PAR bulbs".  In short, I haven't seen directivity, focus, or glare shielding readily available in flat wafer designs.  What is it about the light from wafers that you find 'much better'?  Perhaps there are now wafers that have micro lenses or baffles that offer equivalent control?

@MadMonty you seem to be referring to recessed lights that are designed, selected, installed, and maintained thoughtfully.   No argument.   I just think that's rare.  Good wafers provide bright even light without glare in controllable colors.  Just easy cheap general lighting.   And I think when someone says they have recessed in their kitchen it's reasonable to assume they are just cheap sh*tty 1990s contractor cans with even cheaper, incorrectly sized bulbs in them like fading CFLs that are too small for the fixture.

So the argument is that new wafer lights done well are superior to recessed lighting maintained poorly?  Even put that way, I wouldn't agree:  the best one can expect from the wafers is even overall illumination.  Recessed lighting gives one the ability to enhance the look and feel of a room - and often with rather dramatic results - precisely because of the control its lamps and fixtures allow.  Whether to avail oneself of the benefits of conscious lighting design is an individual's prerogative, but the failure to do so does not render it inferior.

The easiest way is probably to replace the existing switch with a "smart" switch that supports remotes. Something like the Lutron Caseta. Image from Home Depot:

The remote can go anywhere. It is designed so that it can be installed in the wall to look just like a wired switch.
However, there is an important thing to watch out for: How does the switch power itself?
Any electronic device that needs power when "off" has to get that power from somewhere. That is certainly the case here as you want the remote to work, and therefore the wireless receiver has to work, when the light is off. There are several ways that can be done:

Neutral
Ground
Battery
Leak power through circuit

Neutral is, slowly but surely, becoming the preferred method. However, while switch boxes in new houses generally have neutral, older houses often do not have neutral in switch boxes as that requirement was added to the electrical code (NEC) relatively recently. If you have neutral then pretty much any option will work.
Ground is limited by code to a very low level of power. However, most houses built in the last 50 years have ground everywhere, which is more than have neutral in all switch boxes. A switch must be designed to NOT require neutral in order to use ground instead of neutral. I have seen some switches where neutral is preferred but ground instead is OK. But if it actually requires neutral then you can't use ground instead - even though it will probably work, it won't be safe! The flip side is also true: if you have a switch that requires ground and you have an old ungrounded installation, you can't use neutral instead.
Batteries are annoying. But they can work. The Lutron Pico remotes are designed for a 10-year battery life with a very standard CR2032 battery. But the remote only has to send a signal when you press a button. The main switch has to have a receiver on all the time and uses more power.
Leaking power through a circuit used to be a very common and effective method. Unfortunately, it generally does not work well with LED lighting. LED lighting saves so much energy compared to incandescent lighting that replacing a "won't work any more fancy switch" is generally cheaper, due to energy savings, than sticking with incandescents.
